# Learning about mutexes and threads - Question regarding race conditions

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, deadlock

I'm teaching myself a bit about concurrent programming, specifically using mutexes and threads in C++. I've written the following small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
// #include <chrono>

std::mutex M1,M2;

void task_one () {
    std::cout << "AAAA!\n";
    M1.lock();
    // std::cout << "M1 locked in A\n";
    M2.lock();
    // std::cout << "M2 locked in A\n";
    std::cout << "BBBB!\n";
    M2.unlock();
    // std::cout << "M2 unlocked in A\n";
    M1.unlock();
    // std::cout << "M2 unlocked in A\n";
}

void task_two () {
    std::cout << "CCCC!\n";
    M2.lock();
    // std::cout << "M2 locked in B\n";
    M1.lock();
    // std::cout << "M1 locked in B\n";
    std::cout << "DDDD!\n";
    // M1.unlock();
    // std::cout << "M1 unlocked in B\n";
    M2.unlock();
    // std::cout << "M2 unlocked in B\n";
}

int main () {
    std::thread th1 (task_one);
    std::thread th2 (task_two);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    // th1.detach();
    // th2.detach();
    // std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(10);
    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected this code to print

```
AAAA!
CCCC!
```

and then deadlock when `task_one` attempts to acquire the lock on M2 (because `task_two` will have already acquired that lock).
However, it prints

```
AAAA!
BBBB!
CCCC!
DDDD!
```

Why isn't there a deadlock? In addition, is this an example of a race condition, or is this code thread-safe? I think that there is a race condition because if `task_one` can acquire a lock on M2 before `task_two` can, then everything will execute (that is, `task_one` will finish and then allow `task_two` to begin). However, I ran this quite a few times with the same results. Also, if my verbiage as it relates to locks and threads is incorrect, please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

Just because a deadlock *can* happen (as indeed it can in the code as posted), doesn't mean it always *will* happen.

In your case, `task_one` happens to run to completion before `task_two` gets going at all.

Multi-threading is like that: slippery.

Comment: So if my definition of race condition (the sequence of execution impacts the final output) is correct, this code exhibits a race condition?